# How to remove an Array in a List in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to remove the array Removelist in a list Removelist1. If the Removelist array having  one value then it works fine otherwise it will not remove the array.The code is given below:

```
for(int j=0;j<Removelist.length;j++)
{

    System.out.println(Removelist[j]);
if(Removelist1.contains(Removelist[j]))
{
    System.out.println("Exists: "+Removelist[j]);
    Removelist1.remove(Removelist1.indexOf(Removelist[j]));
}
}
```

Comment: Please post more of your code... You have a List of arrays? Are you searching for array elements in a List...

Comment: what is removelist an array of? Is it a basic type or a custom object?

Comment: You have the array as a whole in the list, or just it's elements? Can you complete the header of the for loop? It is missing.

Comment: try **Removelist1.remove(Removelist[j]);**

Answer (score 3):

Try next:

```
String [] remove = {"a","b"};
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add("a");
data.add("s");
data.add("b");
data.removeAll(Arrays.asList(remove));
System.out.println(data);
```

`remove` is array which you need to remove from `List`.

and `data` your `List`.

Output:`[s]`

You needn't to iterate each element of collection `removeAll()` method do it. You need only to cast array to `Collection` like next: `Arrays.asList(remove)`.

For fixing your code you need to change `Removelist1.remove(Removelist1.indexOf(Removelist[j]));` to `Removelist1.remove(Removelist[j]);`.

Comment: It would help to explain what was wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use

```
RemoveList1.removeAll(Arrays.asList(RemoveList));
```

?